# What is the difference between sizeof(*ptr) and sizeof(ptr) in the following code?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am studying about pointers in C++. In the following code I have a pointer to an int. I am not able to understand what's the difference between sizeof(*ptr) and sizeof(ptr)? The sizeof(*ptr) is 4 bytes which I agree to, but why sizeof(ptr) is 8 bytes?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num = 10;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &num;
    cout<<sizeof(*ptr)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(ptr)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
saurabh@saurabh-inspiron:~/Code/Project$ ./p 
4
8
```

Comment: 8 bytes == 64 bits == the size of a memory address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a pointer to an `int` on your platform is 8 bytes.

That's the common case on current desktop computers - corresponding to a 64 bit architecture.

Note two things:

1. The current crop of Intel chips have 48 bit pointers under the hood.
2. The C++ standard allows the size of different pointer types to be different. For example, it might not be the case that `sizeof(double*)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`. On modern desktop platforms they are, but in the old days of separate floating point chips, they might not have been.

Answer (score 3):

If `ptr` is a pointer to an `int`, then `*ptr` is *the `int` that it points to*.

You are showing that on your system, an `int` is **4 bytes**, while a pointer is **8 bytes**.